# Why did Mandana Mishra defend the Sphotavada theory of language?

Tags: history, philosophy, vedanta, advaita, purva-mimamsa

Mandana Mishra was a Purva Mimamsa philosopher who became an Advaitin after losing a debate to the Advaita philosopher Adi Shankaracharya.  He's often identified with Sureshwaracharya, although that's disputed.  Now one of Mandana Mishra's works is the Sphota Siddhi, which seeks to defend Sphotavada.  For those who don't know, Sphotavada is a theory of language advocated by Bhatrihari and other grammarians which states that humans understand language by hearing a Sphota or burst of sound which conveys an entire word or even an entire sentence at once.  This is in contrast to the Varnavada theory advocated by the Purva Mimamsa and Vedanta schools, according to which humans understand language by hearing the sounds of individual letters, and then those letters are combined by the mind into words and sentences.

In any case, [here](https://ia600208.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/6/items/SpotasiddhiOfMandanaMisraK.A.SubramaniaIyer_201602/Spotasiddhi%20Of%20Mandana%20Misra%20-%20K.A.%20Subramania%20Iyer_jp2.zip&file=Spotasiddhi%20Of%20Mandana%20Misra%20-%20K.A.%20Subramania%20Iyer_jp2/Spotasiddhi%20Of%20Mandana%20Misra%20-%20K.A.%20Subramania%20Iyer_0041.jp2&scale=8&rotate=0) is how Mandana Mishra describes the purpose of his Sphota Siddhi:

> In support of [the doctrine of Sphotavada] which has been challenged by certain uncharitable critics, a few arguments are being put forward according to tradition and my understanding.

My question is, why does Mandana Mishra defend Sphotavada? Both of his gurus supported Varnavada rather than Sphotavada.  His first guru, the Purva Mimamsa philosopher Kumarila Bhatta, refutes Sphotavada in [this chapter](https://archive.org/stream/slokavartika015341mbp#page/n331/mode/2up) of his Shloka Vartika. And his second guru, the Advaita philosopher Adi Shankaracharya, refutes Sphotavada in [this section](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34097.htm) of his Brahma Sutra Bhashya.

Was Mandana Mishra just an iconoclast who decided that Sphotavada was right despite what his gurus said?  Or did he have a third guru who believed in Sphotavada?

Comment: 1. There is no "becoming advaitin". Advaita is not a sect like VA or dvaita.  One can go from adherence to one of these specialised philosophies to the grander philosophy but there is no small nook of advaita that people can choose to align with. Advaita is the default and mainstream philosophy propounded by the veda  2.This is the first time I hear that MM is disputed to be Sureswaracharya. 1/2

Comment: 3. You cannot draw the conclusion you drew even based on the cherry picked portions of the texts you provided. See "I do not assume the existence of the sphota. I, on the contrary, actually perceive it" . You are "Concern trolling" @keshavsrinviasan 2/2

Comment: First of all, I disagree with the distinction you make between Advaita and other Vedantic philosophies - I see Visistadvaita as the core philosophy conveyed by the Vedas and other scriptures.  But we're not likely to agree on that issue.  Second of all, the Kanchipuram Shankaracharya Matham is an example of people who distinguish between Mandana Mishra and Sureshwaracharya: http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Preceptors%20of%20Advaita%20-%20Index.html

Comment: @moonstar In any case, what conclusion do I draw that is not warranted?  And where in the text does the quote "I do not assume the existence of Sphota..." occur? (I'm not sure how this quote would contradict anything I've said.) And I'm certainly not concern trolling; I'm genuinely interested in the views of Mandana Mishra, as he's the only member of either the Purva Mimamsa school or the Vedanta school I've come across who believed in Sphotavada.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69662/discussion-on-question-by-keshav-srinivasan-why-did-mandana-mishra-defend-the-sp).

Comment: You first edited the language part out then u added it again, then will u add it again and remove it again? Why are u doing such edits to bump ur posts? Are these allowed?

Comment: @Rickross I just changed my mind about the edit. I want to give it whatever title will give it the most attention during the bounty period.

Comment: I have noticed you always do such trivial edits. Purpose is obvious here. So, i just asked a question on Meta. @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Hinduism and should be deleted.

Comment: @SK Of course it does - it's about the Purva Mimamsa school and Vedanta school, two of the six Astika or orthodox schools of Hindu philosophy.

Comment: last time i checked linguistics is not religion.  How does it matter - "keshav paratvam" holds here.

Comment: @SK Hinduism touches on many aspects of philosophy including the [philosophy of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_language). The reason why the Purva Mimamsa and Vedanta schools care about the philosophy of language is that it's relevant to the Apaurusheyatva or authorlessness of the Vedas. If language is just a human construct, then a text cannot be authorless, because it would have had to be authored after the creation of the language it's written in. And if a language is eternal, what's the relation between word and meaning? That's where Varnavada and Sphotavada come in.

Comment: @SK Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70002/discussion-between-keshav-srinivasan-and-s-k).

Comment: Did Mandana Misra stick to Sphotaka line *even after*  acknowledged defeat from Adi Shankara?

Comment: @Narasimham I think the Sphotasiddhi was composed by Mandanda Mishra after his conversion.  But regardless, both his guru before the conversion, Kumarila Bhatta, and his guru after the conversion, Adi Shankaracharya, were opposed to Sphotavada, so I'm not sure whether the conversion would have affected things.

Comment: Maṇḍana Miśra writing Sphoṭasiddhi doesn't necessarily imply that he agreed with or followed sphoṭavāda really. Vācaspati Miśra wrote commentaries on Nyāyasūtra and Yogasūtra, without taking an Advaitin dārśanika pakṣa. But he was still an Advaitin. In the comm. on Brahmasūtras, he follows Śaṅkara fully. You don't need to be part of a darśana M to hold a dārśanika pakṣa of M in a treatise of M. There is a comm. on Yogasūtras by Śaṅkara and he took the dārśanika pakṣa of Pātañjala Yoga in comm., rather than Vedānta in it.